# Javascript/JQuery if cookie doesn't exist Accept

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a script which checks if a cookie exists. If so it hides a div element with the accept button.If however the cookie doesn't exist then it displays the div. When clicking on the accept button it creates the cookie. It's Working good.

The issue I have is when clicking onto a page that runs the script or refresh the page you can briefly see the div. It's really annoying. Can anyone come up with a solution to prevent this? Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (/cookie-policy/.test(window.location.href)) {
       $('#cookie').hide();
    }
});
window.onload = function() {
if (document.cookie.indexOf("accept=") >= 0) {
  // They've been here before.
  $('#cookie').hide();
}
else {
    $('html, body').css({overflow: 'hidden', height: 'auto'});
}
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cookie-close').click(function(cookie) {  
        document.cookie = "accept=cookies accepted; expires=Sun, 18 Dec 2050 12:00:00 UTC";
        $('html, body').css({overflow: 'auto', height: 'auto'});
        $('#cookie').fadeOut("fast");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have something in your html like this:

```
<div id="cookie">some content!</div>
```

You can add the following to your CSS:

```
#cookie {
    display: none;
}
```

Or

```
<div id="cookie" style="display: none;">content here</div>
```

This will make the div invisible on page load, giving your script time to run.

Comment: so now with this the popup does not occur at all

Comment: Ah, it might be then because jquery is using visible, rather than display to show the element. Try "visibility: hidden" instead?